# How to remove last word from a string

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have a text field in flash which contains the following string:

```
txtFld.text = " Mr. Suresh Kumar has written this article"
```

Now, what I want to do is, I want to remove the last word out of this and look like:

```
txtFld.text = " Mr. Suresh Kumar has written this"
```

Please Help,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`.slice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-77d2.html) and [`.lastIndexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118ccf9c47f-7b90.html):

```
var base:String = "Mr. Suresh Kumar has written this article";

// Slice up until the last whitespace character.
var trunc:String = base.slice(0, base.lastIndexOf(" "));
trace(trunc);
```

Because AS2 does not have regex support, you should make sure the input is trimmed beforehand (whitespace removed from the front and end).

Comment: @Cherniv Thanks - your approach is more common though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    var text = txtFld.text;   // Saving text field' value in temporary variable
    text = text.split(" ");   // Splitting it at space delimiter
    text.splice(text.length-1 , 1); // Throwing out the last word
    txtFld.text = text.join(" ");   // Concatenating whole thing back
```